# spring cloud stream for multitenant services

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I’m configuring spring cloud stream for service orchestration. Created a binder for Tibco EMS, however due to resource constraint we have multiple EMS clusters for different clients. Such as client A has a specific EMS connection url,  B has a different URL.
 Is it possible to configure spring cloud stream to work with tenant specific connections or destinations? Such as client A will have topic MyTopic-A, MyTopic-B for client B and so on. Based on the tenant context, the sink or source will consume/publish messages to that specific topic/queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Connecting to Multiple Systems](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-systems).

Declare multiple binders and assign a binder to each binding.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. My problem is that the service is generic and tenant agnostic. However, the tenant numbers are variable.
A sample service takes a request, processes it and sends a response.
    
    `@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Source.OUTPUT)
    public Response process(Request request) {
    //Process request 
        return new Response(payload);
    } 
`
I can't define a fixed number of binders such as three binders. When a new tenant appears, it comes with a unique connection URL and the same service should be able to handle it.

Comment: Can I configure Spring cloud-config to have tenant-specific connection factory URL and when new tenant info is added a new service would be spawn for that tenant? The service can read the connection URL for it and pass that information to the binder.
[Service Diagram](https://github.com/ignitewala/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/service-cluster.png)

Comment: I think the (possibly) only way to do that would be to fire up a child application context for each tenant. Most of the business logic can be in the parent context, but the bindings would have to be in the children.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Can we configure spring cloud config server to provide the connection properties to the binder?

Comment: I think that using a property placeholder should work `spring.cloud.stream.custom.binder.url=${tennant1.url}`.